# C++ Counting Quicksort Comparisons <Unsolved>

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, data-structures

I am working on a project that asks us to implement different sorts and add counter variables to measure the runtime with different array sizes.

**My problem is that the output is not the same as the expected output**

I already completed the insertion sort and correctly counts the number of comparisons.

I am allowed to use reference parameter.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Output:[Updated from Answer]

```
Quick sort           16          384         6401        74378
```

Expected Output:

```
Array Size:          10         100         1000         10000
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Quick Sort           35         630         10292        132882
```

Whats inside the contents of the array for array size 10:

The contents stay Constant with the used **seed**.

```
Insertion sort

[ 935, 942, 697, 299, 382, 579, 408, 181, 366, 505 ] //unsorted
[ 181, 299, 366, 382, 408, 505, 579, 697, 935, 942 ] //sorted
```

Program: [Updated From Answer]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
      /******************************/
      /* Start of Quick Sort Algorithm */
      /******************************/



static const int MIN_SIZE  = 10; // Smallest size of an array that quicksort will sort

/**
 * Sorts the items in an array into ascending order.
 */
template<class ItemType>
int insertionSort(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last) {
  int count = 0;
    for (int unsorted = first + 1; unsorted <= last; unsorted++) {
        ItemType nextItem = theArray[unsorted];
        int loc = unsorted;
        while ((loc > first) && (count++,theArray[loc - 1] > nextItem)) {
            theArray[loc] = theArray[loc - 1];
            loc--;
        }
        theArray[loc] = nextItem;
    }
    return count;
}

/**
 * Arranges two specified array entries into sorted order by
 * exchanging them, if necessary.
 * */
template<class ItemType>
void order(ItemType theArray[], int i, int j) {
    if (theArray[i] > theArray[j]) {
        std::swap(theArray[i], theArray[j]);
    }
}

/**
 * Arranges the first, middle, and last entry in an array in sorted order.
 */
template<class ItemType>
int sortFirstMiddleLast(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last) {
    int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
    order(theArray, first, mid); // Make theArray[first] <= theArray[mid]
    order(theArray, mid, last);  // Make theArray[mid] <= theArray[last]
    order(theArray, first, mid); // Make theArray[first] <= theArray[mid]

    return mid;
}

/**
 * Partitions the entries in an array about a pivot entry for quicksort.
 */
template<class ItemType>
int partition(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last,int &counter) {
    // Choose pivot using median-of-three selection
    int pivotIndex = sortFirstMiddleLast(theArray, first, last);

    // Reposition pivot so it is last in the array
    std::swap(theArray[pivotIndex], theArray[last - 1]);
    pivotIndex = last - 1;
    ItemType pivot = theArray[pivotIndex];

    // Determine the regions S1 and S2
    int indexFromLeft = first + 1;
    int indexFromRight = last - 2;

    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        // Locate first entry on left that is >= pivot
        while (theArray[indexFromLeft] < pivot) {
          counter++;//I incremented Count here
          indexFromLeft = indexFromLeft + 1;
        }

        // Locate first entry on right that is <= pivot
        while (theArray[indexFromRight] > pivot) {
          counter++;
          indexFromRight = indexFromRight - 1;
        }

        if (indexFromLeft < indexFromRight) {
            std::swap(theArray[indexFromLeft], theArray[indexFromRight]);
            indexFromLeft = indexFromLeft + 1;
            indexFromRight = indexFromRight - 1;
        }
        else {
            done = true;
        }
    }

    // Place pivot in proper position between S1 and S2, and mark its new location
    std::swap(theArray[pivotIndex], theArray[indexFromLeft]);
    pivotIndex = indexFromLeft;

    return pivotIndex;
}

/**
 * Sorts an array into ascending order. Uses the quick sort with
 * median-of-three pivot selection for arrays of at least MIN_SIZE
 * entries, and uses the insertion sort for other arrays.
 */
template<class ItemType>
int quicksort(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last) {
    int result = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    if (last - first + 1 < MIN_SIZE) {
        result = insertionSort(theArray, first, last);
    }
    else {
        // Create the partition: S1 | Pivot | S2
        int pivotIndex = partition(theArray, first, last,counter);
        // Sort subarrays S1 and S2
         result += quicksort(theArray, first, pivotIndex - 1);
         result += quicksort(theArray, pivotIndex + 1, last);
         result += counter;
    }
    return result; //return final count
}


      /******************************/
      /* Start of Sorting Benchmark  */
      /******************************/
int* makeRandomArray(int n, int seed) {
    srand(seed);
    int * a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 1000;
    }
    return a;
}

int main(){
    const int seed = 9000;
    int *a;

    /******************************/
    /* Start of Quick Sort    */
    /******************************/
    std::cout << "Quick sort";

    int n = 10;
    a = makeRandomArray(10, seed);
    std::cout <<std::setw(13)<< quicksort(a, 0, n-1);
    delete[] a;

    n = 100;
    a = makeRandomArray(100, seed);
    std::cout <<std::setw(13)<< quicksort(a, 0, n-1);
    delete[] a;

    n = 1000;
    a = makeRandomArray(1000, seed);
    std::cout <<std::setw(13)<< quicksort(a, 0, n-1);
    delete[] a;

    n = 10000;
    a = makeRandomArray(10000, seed);
    std::cout <<std::setw(13)<< quicksort(a, 0, n-1)<<std::endl;
    delete[] a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you create 2 accounts to ask questions? You must merge them: [Is there a way to combine or merge Stack Exchange accounts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336512/995714), https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1):

In quick sort, the comparisons are made when the partition method/function is looking for elements that break the rule that elements smaller than the pivot must be on the left of the pivot and elements larger than it must be on the right. These two whiles do exactly this. The first one keeps going to the right while the current element is smaller than the pivot (first set of comparisons). The second while do the opposite operation, i.e., it keeps going to the left while the current element is bigger than the pivot, doing the second set of comparisons. If the left index is smaller than the right index, it means that it found an element that is bigger than the pivot on the left and an element that is smaller than the pivot on the right, so it will swap them. The process continues, until the left index pass throught the right one. When it finishes, all the left values are smaller than the pivot and all the right values are bigger than the pivot, so it swaps the pivot with the last element of the smaller side and returns the pivot position, since now, the pivot is in the correct position and the "middle" of that partition was found, allowing the sorting process to continue to the left partition and to the right partition.

```
while (theArray[indexFromLeft] < pivot) {
    // count here
    indexFromLeft = indexFromLeft + 1;
}

while (theArray[indexFromRight] > pivot) {
    // and here
    indexFromRight = indexFromRight - 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I updated my program, I added a counter++ in those 2 spots as suggested. It's not giving the expected output.

Comment: Putting the count inside the `while`-body will not count failed comparisons.

Comment: @NinjaBanna If this does not answer your question, you should not accept it as answer ...

Comment: @chtz Unmarked it as answer, But what do you mean by not counting failed comparisons